# swagger ui spec for downloading zip file

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui

I'm in trouble for creating API for downloading a zip file.
Here is my API in open API 3.0.1

```
 /download:
    get:
      parameters:
        - name: number
          in: query
          description: The Booking Number which you want to download Files
          required: true
          style: form
          explode: true
          schema:
            type: string
          example: attachment; filename="name.zip"
      responses:
        '200':
          description: OK
          headers:
            Content-Disposition:
              style: simple
              explode: false
              schema:
                type: string
                format: binary
          content:
            application/octet-stream:
              schema:
                type: string
                description: Used only with `application/zip` responses
                example: attachment; filename="name.zip"
```

it shows like this and if I try to download it, the type of file is not zip [image of download file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuDdk.png)

this kind of file type is given
[file type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fstY6.png)

what I want is for that zip file to be downloaded when I test/call the API.